# Same custom field name at Contact Form seems to be different for each logged in user

Tags: developer, smarty

We've tried to alter some custom fields display (namely, make some fields display data only, not editable text field). It seems that all custom fields logic is inside **templates\CRM\Custom\Form\CustomField.tpl file**
So, we've tried to do something like this

```
{if $element.data_type neq 'Date' AND $element.element_name eq "custom_358_437"}
{$element.element_value}
```

where **custom_358_437** is a field name picked via form html code inspector. 
All seems fine till another logged in user looks at the same form; it turns that the field gets "random" another name  (say, **custom_15_415** for other user and **custom_47_412** for yet another user), which seems to be pretty odd.

Not sure if it's "by design" (yet not sure why same field name should be changed for each user); if it is so, is there any logic in field name generation (may be current user ID is being used, although it doesn't look like this)? In a broader sense, how do we target custom field for making changes, if not by field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not  the exact answer, just a workaround one may find useful: field label stays unchanged even if field name changes, which makes possible element catch by label, e.g.:

```
 AND ($element.label eq "Element label")
```